# How do you know if your current build is stable?

Tags: git, git-flow

I've come across many branching strategies, and some of them embrace idea of a 'stable' build branch - a branch containing the most qualified state of a project. However I didn't find any unified success criteria, that can be used to understand if a build is stable and ready for being pushed to that branch.

The question may be too subjective, and heavily depends on a project peculiarities, but if you can provide me with any example, i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change things on a feature branch. You then test whether those changes work as intended and don't break existing funcionality (regression).

Then when finishing the feature, i.e. merging it back to the develop branch, you run the tests again, because another branch that was merged into develop while this feature branch was being worked on might conflict with the feature's changes.

When all tests succeed, you can push the merged develop branch. After pushing your CI server ideally should run the tests yet again.

This process is greatly aided by (read: nearly impossible without) automated testing.